# Can I get the max date of a group without doing a self join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, maxdate

I have this monstrous query here:

```
SELECT t.technician_id AS techID, CONCAT(t.first_name, ' ', t.last_name) AS technicianName, h.date, p.name
FROM technician t
JOIN technician_date td ON t.technician_id = td.technician_id
JOIN hours_input_on_date h ON h.id = td.hours_input_on_date_id
JOIN technician_date_project tdp ON tdp.technician_date_id = td.technician_date_id
JOIN projects p ON p.id = tdp.project_id
JOIN(
    SELECT h.date, p.name
    FROM technician t
    JOIN technician_date td ON t.technician_id = td.technician_id
    JOIN hours_input_on_date h ON h.id = td.hours_input_on_date_id
    JOIN technician_date_project tdp ON tdp.technician_date_id = td.technician_date_id
    JOIN projects p ON p.id = tdp.project_id
    GROUP BY h.date, p.name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) temp ON h.date = temp.date AND p.name = temp.name
JOIN(
    SELECT MAX(date) AS latestDate, name
    FROM(
        SELECT h.date, p.name
        FROM technician t
        JOIN technician_date td ON t.technician_id = td.technician_id
        JOIN hours_input_on_date h ON h.id = td.hours_input_on_date_id
        JOIN technician_date_project tdp ON tdp.technician_date_id = td.technician_date_id
        JOIN projects p ON p.id = tdp.project_id
        GROUP BY h.date, p.name
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
    GROUP BY t.name) temp1 ON temp1.latestDate = temp.date AND temp1.name = temp.name;
```

What this is doing is getting the technicians and projects for cases when more than one technician worked on the same project on the same day. See my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301617/how-to-avoid-groups-but-require-a-minimum-count) for clarification. This is what the first group of joins, and the first join subquery accomplish.

Now, I would just like to get the *latest* group of techs who worked on a project on the same day. I've added another self join that gets the max date from the group of projects where multiple techs worked on the same day. Is there a more efficient way to remove that last `JOIN` block and still limit the grouping to the latest date, or is a self-join the only way to go?

For more clarification, let's say I took the last `JOIN` block out, I would see something like this:

```
| tech |    date    | project |
+------+------------+---------+
| Adam | 2014-12-04 |  Math   |
| John | 2014-12-04 |  Math   |
| Jane | 2014-12-04 |  Math   |
| Adam | 2014-12-05 |  Math   |
| John | 2014-12-05 |  Math   |
```

I would like to only see the last two rows, because it was the most recent group for that project, but can I do it more efficiently than joining all of my tables *again*?

**EDIT**

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9858/2) that helps demonstrate the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could nest a "max(date) group by name" in your subquery:

```
SELECT t.technician_id AS techID, CONCAT(t.first_name, ' ', t.last_name) AS technicianName, h.date, p.name
FROM technician t
JOIN technician_date td ON t.technician_id = td.technician_id
JOIN hours_input_on_date h ON h.id = td.hours_input_on_date_id
JOIN technician_date_project tdp ON tdp.technician_date_id = td.technician_date_id
JOIN projects p ON p.id = tdp.project_id
JOIN(

    SELECT max(date) date, name from (

    SELECT h.date, p.name
    FROM technician t
    JOIN technician_date td ON t.technician_id = td.technician_id
    JOIN hours_input_on_date h ON h.id = td.hours_input_on_date_id
    JOIN technician_date_project tdp ON tdp.technician_date_id = td.technician_date_id
    JOIN projects p ON p.id = tdp.project_id
    GROUP BY h.date, p.name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

    ) subtemp
    group by name

) temp ON h.date = temp.date AND p.name = temp.name;
```

Comment: This worked in the SQL Fiddle. I go back into work on Thursday and I'll run it against the actual data set and see if it is faster. Thanks!

Comment: If you're curious, both queries were really close in time but this solution was *often* faster than the other. However, my dataset is really small so it might be a bad judgement of how different they really are.

Answer (score 0):

By adding MAX to the first query around the h.date like this

```
SELECT t.technician_id AS techID, CONCAT(t.first_name, ' ', t.last_name) AS technicianName,          MAX(h.date), p.name
FROM technician t
JOIN technician_date td ON t.technician_id = td.technician_id
JOIN hours_input_on_date h ON h.id = td.hours_input_on_date_id
JOIN technician_date_project tdp ON tdp.technician_date_id = td.technician_date_id
JOIN projects p ON p.id = tdp.project_id
JOIN(
SELECT h.date, p.name
FROM technician t
JOIN technician_date td ON t.technician_id = td.technician_id
JOIN hours_input_on_date h ON h.id = td.hours_input_on_date_id
JOIN technician_date_project tdp ON tdp.technician_date_id = td.technician_date_id
JOIN projects p ON p.id = tdp.project_id
GROUP BY h.date, p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) temp ON h.date = temp.date AND p.name = temp.name;
```

You will get the data you need in the second query.

Comment: This won't work. It will only return one row because it is an aggregate function that's trying to group everything, but I don't want to group anything but be selective of the rows.